# arbotix_python arbotix servos not recognized

Tags: ros, arbotix, ax12, servo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have purchased an arbotix robocontroller but the servos are not being recognized when I run arbotix_python.
I am able to successfully compile and upload the ros.pde firmware without error (although I did originally get complaints about that arduino not being on option for the controller that I had to work around).
So no errors of any kind, the board is being powered by an external LiPo, the servo lights up briefly when power is turned on, but again, when I run the arbotix_python, no servos are seen. Any suggestions would be appreciated as I have no errors to give me a lead on what to try next.

Output:
scott@wilson:~$ rosrun arbotix_python terminal.py /dev/ttyUSB0
ArbotiX Terminal --- Version 0.1
Copyright 2011 Vanadium Labs LLC

> > ls
> > .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....
> > .... .... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38776/arbotix_python-arbotix-servos-not-recognized/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-07-13**:
Attention @fergs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you set IDs for each of the servos? If you have multiple new servos attached, they each ship with ID 1, and none of them will be able to respond.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2012-07-15**:
That is exactly what I am attempting to do, one servo at a time. The plan being to run ls, see what the servo is currently set to, and them mv it to what I need it to be. The problem is, it cannot recognize what it is set to in the first place, so I can't move it to anything.

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2012-07-15**:
So the core of the issue is, if I am getting no compile errors on the ros.pde and it uploads just fine, then why can't I identify what the current servo ID is when I only have a single servo attached a time? I have tried it with several known good servos and same problem, so not related to the servo

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2012-07-15**:
Hi again Fergs, I may have found a clue. I re-ran the arbotix_python node. When I first power on the board. All lights blink on as expected on the FTDI cable and the Arbotix board.  But when I issue the ls command,the communication light stays on solid.

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2012-09-25**:
Did you ever resolve this issue?  I am having the same problem.  Attention @Scott

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-09-26**:
did you guys solve the issue, I have same problem, @fergs @Scott